# Issue uploading image

Tags: php, file-upload

I have been following this tutorial for "Uploading/Storing an Image inside a MySQL Database" on YouTube, but have this issue for two days, and I have been trying to debug the last two days for this issue, but can't figure out what it is.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
// connect to database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("databaseimage") or die(mysql_error());

// file properties
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if (!isset($file))
    echo "Please select an image.";
else
{
 $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
 $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
 $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

 if ($image_size==FALSE)
    echo "That's not an image.";
else
{
    if (!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO store VALUES ('', '$image_name',     
    '$image')"))
        echo "Problem uploading image.";
    else
    {
     $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
     echo "Image uploaded.<p />Your image:<p /><img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";
    }

} 
}
?>
```

Whenever I try to upload a .png or .jpeg file, the code hits the "if" case inside of the "else" case and does not pass that and echoes out "Problem uploading image."
I did exactly as the tutorial did, where the person in the tutorial is able to pass that "if" case and actually hit the last part and echoes "Image uploaded."

Anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is throwing you an error of *Problem uploading image* than it is probably entering into `if` condition as your query is failing, you should use `mysql_error()` to read a friendly message, that what makes your query fail.

```
echo "Problem uploading image.".mysql_error($connection); 
//Replace connection with the connection var
```

> Note: Code is totally dirty, also it uses deprecated `mysql_()`. So
>   start learning `mysqli_()` or PDO, also your code is prone to SQL Injections, better sanitize the data and escape the strings before inserting any user provided data in the database

Also you are not checking the file extension and the file size which is uploaded by the user, so you must do that too for security reasons and to save huge files uploaded on your server...

Comment: That shows me that the error is, "Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1". So I placed an arbitrary number within the blank '' before '$image_name' and it makes it work, but I thought that I don't need to put in a number because through the database, I set up the id to be PRIMARY and AUTO-INCREMENT. What should I put in this blank '' to fix this problem? (I don't want to keep that arbitrary number in there because it doesn't feel right)

Comment: @user2512888 You are using insert without column names, if your id is AI, than simply use this query `"INSERT INTO store (image_name_column_name, another_column_name) VALUES ('$image_name', '$image')"` `//replace the column names with the real ones`

Comment: I see, Mr. Alien you sir are a magician, let me become your apprentice. But really how do you learn all of this and have so much knowledge? (Do you just read all of the documentation?) Teach me the ways of the Force.

Comment: @user2512888 Thank you, and I just learn from various resources and I develop different projects, encounter certain issues, I debug and that's how I keep learning, and if this solved your problem, you can mark the answer as correct so that others can refer this :)

Comment: @user2512888 You can see the info in my profile, you'll get a base_64 encoded string which holds my email, you can just decrypt that [here](http://www.base64decode.org/)..

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sending you an email! :)

Comment: Email has been sent! :)